# .NET DNS class powershell background job possible?

Tags: .net, powershell, dns

I found this script which I modified a bit to take in the hostnames from a file:

http://tompaps.blogspot.com/2015/04/verify-forward-and-reverse-dns-records.html

It pretty much iterates through each name in the file, pings it, converts the returned IP into a string and performs a reverse lookup on the IP. It works, but when I have 600+ machines to go through performance is no bueno. I know with test-connection there's an -asjob parameter I can use to run asynchronous jobs which does the forwardlookup job in seconds but does anyone know a way to mimic this behavior for the reverse lookup?

I found a post on this forum suggesting you can do something similar using the .NET process class but I've just been working with Powershell for a few months and can't seem to decipher the MSDN docs.

Comment: I use Invoke-Parallel to parallelize actions https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-Parallel-Parallel-377fd430

Comment: @MickyBalladelli `Invoke-Parallel -scriptfile c:\work\reverse.ps1 -inputobject $(get-content     c:work\test.txt) -runspacetimeout 10 -throttle 10 ` Im using this line to try and run a test. the code in the reverse.ps1 file is as follows: `$hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_).HostName $results = @() foreach ($host in $hostname) { if ($hostname) {$results += $_ + "," + $hostname} else {results += $_ + "," + "No Hostname Found"}} $result | out-file c:\work\Results.txt` output is blank. Do you see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Try using the `-ScriptBlock` parameter instead of scriptfile, it's how I use it. The `-ImportVariables` parameter is also interesting to let the runspaces import the variables you have defined.

Comment: yeah that's what i figured too, i just did a test with the scriptblock parameter and same result. Weird thing is if i take out the foreach loop, and just do something like `$hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_).HostName $hostname` it outputs just fine to the console..must be something about the if/else statements

Comment: You need to simplify your script, invoke-parallel replaces the foreach. I think one of the examples at the link I gave you pings machines and shows how to use it (examples 3 https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-Parallel-Parallel-377fd430)

Comment: i got it to work, although the outputting to a file is still funky. for now im just going to have it output to the console and i'll just copy and paste the results to a text file manually. Thanks for all the help, I'm still pretty new with powershell so just trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone's interested I ended up doing the following:

```
   Import-Module 'C:\Users\Lia Cha\Documents\Windows Powershell\Modules\Invoke-Parallel.psm1'

   $machines = Get-Content C:\work\hostnames.txt

   Invoke-Parallel -InputObject $machines -RunspaceTimeout 10 -Throttle 10 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ScriptBlock {
   $obj = "" | Select ComputerName,Ping,IPNumber,ForwardLookup,ReverseLookup,Result  
   $obj.ComputerName = $_  

  # ping each host  
  if(Test-Connection $_ -quiet -Count 1){  
       $obj.Ping = "OK"  
 $obj.Result = "OK"  
  }  
  else{  
       $obj.Ping = "Error"  
 $obj.Result = "Error"  
  }  

  # lookup IP addresses of the given host  
  [array]$IPAddresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($obj.ComputerName) | ?{$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"} | %{$_.IPAddressToString}  

  # caputer count of IPs  
  $obj.IPNumber = ($IPAddresses | measure).count  

  # if there were IPs returned from DNS, go through each IP  
    if($IPAddresses){  
 $obj.ForwardLookup = "OK"  

    $IPAddresses | %{  
         $tmpreverse = $null  

            # perform reverse lookup on the given IP  
         $tmpreverse = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_).HostName 
         if($tmpreverse){  

                 # if the returned host name is the same as the name being processed from the input, the result is OK  
              if($tmpreverse -ieq $obj.ComputerName){  
                   $obj.ReverseLookup += "$_ : OK `n"  
              }  
              else{  
                   $obj.ReverseLookup += "$_ different hostname: $tmpreverse `n"  
                   $obj.Result = "Error"  
              }  
         }  
         else{  
              $obj.ReverseLookup = "No host found"  
              $obj.Result = "Error"  
         }  
 }  
  }  
  else{  
       $obj.ForwardLookup = "No IP found"  
       $obj.Result = "Error"  
  }  

  # return the output object  
  $obj | ft -AutoSize | out-string -width 4096 | out-file c:\work\Results.txt -Append}
```

This ran over 450+ machines in about 4mins.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it up in a scriptblock and do Start-Job in a foreach loop to do the following for forward and reverse lookup:

```
$ComputerName= ‘computername here’
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(“$ComputerName”).IPAddressToString

$ComputerIPAddress = ‘that computer ip here'
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ComputerIPAddress).HostName
```

For example

```
$whateverlist = Get-Content .\yourlistofservers.txt

# or you can..

$whateverlist = @"
machine1
machine2
machine3
etc
"@

$Scriptblock = {
param($machine);

    $pingOk = Test-Connection -cn $machine -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -EA silentlyContinue
        if ($pingOk)
        {

            # Do whatever if it responds to pinging
            # Maybe store the property in a list, put it out to a file etc.

            [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(“$machine”).IPAddressToString



            # Use whatever method you like to get IP of the computer, even use the above output.
            # Me being lazy:
            $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(“$machine”).IPAddressToString


            [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ip).HostName

        }
}

# Then you can get the job, do whatever. Do it in a foreach for best results.
foreach ($machine in $whateverlist)
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $machine
}


# To crack open the eggs and get the goodies:
Receive-Job * -Keep | Out-File ".\whatevermanijustworkhere.txt"
```

Here's a clean copy:

```
$whateverlist = Get-Content .\yourlistofservers.txt

$whateverlist = @"
machine1
machine2
machine3
etc
"@

$Scriptblock = {
param($machine);

    $pingOk = Test-Connection -cn $machine -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -EA silentlyContinue
        if ($pingOk)
        {
            $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(“$machine”).IPAddressToString
            $ip

            [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ip).HostName

        }
}


foreach ($machine in $whateverlist)
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $machine
}

Receive-Job * -Keep | Out-File ".\whatevermanijustworkhere.txt"
```

## Source:

https://adsecurity.org/?p=305

Comment: so i was able to combine some of the logic from your script with the original source script i was working from to get the output i wanted but I tested the script with a file containing just 7 machines and it still takes a while to get the info. Don't want to run this on over 600 machines. I'll see if there's an easier/faster way.

Comment: @NiagNtawv I've done similar work with ~560 machines, and time till completion is about 10-15 minutes. The main resource is the Test-Connection. You can get rid of the $pingOk logic block and just fire-and-forget the System.Net.DNS static methods if you don't care for errors flooding the screen.

Make sure you're using Start-Job/Get-Job/Receive Job to parallelize these operations. Otherwise, if you're waiting for a foreach... you're doing them one at a time.

Comment: @NiagNtawv If you want to cut down on time for the reverse and forward lookup, consider doing just a Ping operation on all your machines, outputting the ones that respond to another list, then do the rev/forward lookups on just that list. You'll get the lookup results pretty quick that way.